# How to formulate T-SQL to avoid a primary key constraint?

Tags: t-sql, exists

I am trying to develop a query to just return non-duplicate records so that I can add these to my database, but I keep getting this error:

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
>   Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_j5c_MasterMeasures'.
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.j5c_MasterMeasures'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

And this is my latest query I am using:

```
CREATE TABLE #GOOD_RECORDS3 (STUDENTID VARCHAR(50), MEASUREDATE SMALLDATETIME, 
measurename VARCHAR(100), LabelName VARCHAR(100), score_10 VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO #GOOD_RECORDS3
select A.studentid, A.measuredate, B.measurename, B.LabelName, A.score_10 
from [J5C_Measures_Sys] A join [J5C_ListBoxMeasures_Sys] B on 
A.MeasureID = B.MeasureID
where score_10 is not null and score_10 <> '0' 
except
select A.studentid, A.measuredate, B.measurename, B.LabelName, A.score_10
from [J5C_Measures_Sys] A join [J5C_ListBoxMeasures_Sys] B on 
A.MeasureID = B.MeasureID
where score_10 is not null and score_10 <> '0'
GROUP BY A.studentid, A.measuredate, B.measurename, B.LabelName, A.score_10
having COUNT(A.score_10) > 1

delete #GOOD_RECORDS3
from #GOOD_RECORDS3 a
join sysobjects so on so.name = 'J5C_Measures_Sys' AND so.type = 'u'
join syscolumns sc on so.id = sc.id and sc.name = 'score_10'
join [J5C_MeasureNamesV2_Sys] v on v.Score_field_id = sc.name
WHERE A.SCORE_10 IS NOT NULL AND A.STUDENTID IS NOT NULL AND 
A.MEASUREID IS NOT NULL
and exists (select 1 from J5C_MasterMeasures M
 where M.StudentID = A.StudentID
and M.MeasureID = A.MeasureID)

Insert into J5C_MasterMeasures (studentid, measuredate, measureid, nce)
select A.studentid, A.measuredate, a.MEASUREID, A.score_10
from #GOOD_RECORDS3 a
join sysobjects so on so.name = 'J5C_Measures_Sys' AND so.type = 'u'
join syscolumns sc on so.id = sc.id and sc.name = 'score_10'
join [J5C_MeasureNamesV2_Sys] v on v.Score_field_id = sc.name
WHERE A.SCORE_10 IS NOT NULL AND A.STUDENTID IS NOT NULL AND 
A.MEASUREID IS NOT NULL
```

The confusing part about this is that MeasureId from M5C_Measures_Sys = `B.measurename + ' ' + B.Labelname`. This is some sample data from `#GOOD_RECORDS3`:

```
1   2006-03-01 00:00:00 ISAT Reading ISAT Reading   564
10005   2003-11-17 00:00:00 TerraNova Reading TerraNova Reading     19
10005   2003-11-17 00:00:00 TerraNova Science TerraNova Science     26
10005   2003-11-17 00:00:00 TerraNova Total Battery TerraNova Total Battery     22
10005   2003-11-17 00:00:00 TerraNova Total Language TerraNova Total Language   43
```

So you can see that `b.measurename = b.labelname`. The error above happens on insert.

Result of your answer query below:

```
1   2006-03-01 00:00:00 ISAT Reading    ISAT Reading    564
10005   2003-11-17 00:00:00 TerraNova Reading   TerraNova Reading   19
10005   2003-11-17 00:00:00 TerraNova Science   TerraNova Science   26
10005   2003-11-17 00:00:00 TerraNova Total Battery TerraNova Total Battery     22
10005   2003-11-17 00:00:00 TerraNova Total Language    TerraNova Total Language    43
```

Comment: A little confused What is the primary key?

Comment: are the records exact duplicates or is it just the values in the PK field that are similar

Answer (score 0):

A little out of topic...

Instead of using `CREATE TABLE #GOOD_RECORDS3` you can do `DECLARE @Good_Records3 TABLE (FieldDefinition...).`

If the primarykey is on the column `measureid` then you have still duplicated ids returned from the query.

What does the query

```
select A.studentid, A.measuredate, a.MEASUREID, A.score_10 
from #GOOD_RECORDS3 a 
join sysobjects so on so.name = 'J5C_Measures_Sys' AND so.type = 'u' 
join syscolumns sc on so.id = sc.id and sc.name = 'score_10' 
join [J5C_MeasureNamesV2_Sys] v on v.Score_field_id = sc.name 
WHERE A.SCORE_10 IS NOT NULL AND A.STUDENTID IS NOT NULL AND A.MEASUREID IS NOT NULL
```

return? No duplicate `MEASUREID-values`?

Comment: Sorry can u look at my updated query please?  Now my #GOOD_RECORDS3 table has measurename and labelname columns in place of measureID

Comment: I just added the output of your query to my description at the end.

Comment: Hmm. Are you sure that the table J5C_MasterMeasures is empty before you insert the records to it?

Comment: And what is the J5C_Measures_Sys? Table or View?

Comment: J5C_MasterMeasures is not empty before I enter records into it.  And J5C_Measures_Sys is a table.

Answer (score 0):

I consider the problem comes when inserting to J5C_MasterMeasures table the records fetched in to #GOOD_RECORDS3 table. Please be sure what J5C_MasterMeasures PRIMARY KEY is. Then print #GOOD_RECORDS3 records to look for possible duplicates that may violate J5C_MasterMeasures primary key constraint.

Hope that helps,

Comment: sort of but can you recommend the syntax for this?  PK = StudentID, MeasureDate, (MeasureName + ' ' + LabelName)

Answer (score 0):

First declare a table for storing duplicate details in

```
declare @dupetable table(did int, dcount int)
```

Then declare two variables, one for storing the total number of records with duplicates and one as a loop counter:

```
declare @dupecount int, @loopcounter int
```

Then populate the duplicates table with a list of records that have duplicates and the number of duplicates each one has:

```
insert into @dupetable  --Populate duplicate table
(did, dcount)
select id, COUNT(*)
from #GOOD_RECORDS3  
group by id                 --Replace ID with whatever the primary key is
having COUNT(*) > 1
```

Next, get the total number of records with duplicates:

```
select @dupecount = COUNT(*)    
from @dupetable
```

Then initialize the loop counter:

```
set @loopcounter = 0
```

The code should then loop through the table of duplicates, selecting the top record, removing all the duplicate entries for it and then deleting it from the temporary @dupetable:

```
while  @loopcounter < @dupecount   --Loop through duplicate records
begin
select * from @dupetable 
set @loopcounter = @loopcounter  + 1    --Increase the counter by 1
Declare @ldid int, @ldcount int         --Declare variables for storing the duplicate id and the number of dupes
select top 1 @ldid = did, @ldcount = dcount  --Populate those variables
from @dupetable 
delete from @dupetable      --Remove record from dupe table
where did = @ldid 
declare @rcval int      --Declare variable for setting rowcount
set @rcval = @ldcount - 1   --Set the rowcount val to the number of duplicate rows -1
set rowcount  @rcval        --Set the rowcount val to the number of duplicate rows -1
delete from @testtbl        --Delete the duplicate records from the table
where id = @ldid
end     --End loop
```

It's not too elegant, but I believe it works.

Comment: great comments, however, all of my fields in @dupetable are varchars so I am getting cannot convert from string error.  And my ID is a composite PK of 3 columns.  And this ID does not always look like a number.  Most of the entries are string like '2009456', but a few are like 'L'

Comment: you'll need to declare @ldid as a varchar then instead of an int.


the datatype of your PK should not matter, this script finds records that have matching PK values and deletes all but 1. you just need to change the datatypes of @dupetable and @ldid accordingly